# Using .find method does not return object from parsed JSON

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js 3 but I don't think that is related to my problem. I'm calling localStorage to get a JSON array of post objects, parsing it, and using an id to find the post. I'm getting the id from the route with no problem, but searching the parsed array with .find is returning undefined.

Post.vue file

```
    created() {
        this.postId = this.$route.params.id;
        console.log("******    POST ID *********");
        console.log(this.postId);

        var posts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("posts"));
        console.log("******    POSTS ARRAY *********");
        console.log(posts);

        this.post = posts.find(post => post.id === this.postId);
        console.log("****** POST *********");
        console.log(this.post);
        
    }
```

[Here's the Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEGKc.png)

Comment: In Javascript, `===` compares data type as well as the value.  So you need to use `==` to compare string and number values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `this.postId` is string and the type of each object's id in `posts` array is number. So you can use `==` instead of `===`. Or change the type of `this.postId` to number using `parseInt`.

Comment: That was it! how do I mark a question as the answer? this is my first question on here

Comment: You can find checkmark below the upvote/downvote buttons.